# I cannot get the About Component to display on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-dom-server

I am trying to have my React code display. I followed an [ecommerce website YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=377AQ0y6LPA&t=1273s) and I have tried everything to get it to display. I have read up on React routers and switches, but I really cant spot my mistake.

The `Switch` and `Router`

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
        <Products
            products={products}
            onAddToCart={handleAddToCart}
            handleUpdateCartQty
        />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/about">
        <About About={About} />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/cart">
        <Cart
            cart={cart}
            handleUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty}
            handleRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart}
            handleEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart}
        />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/checkout" exact>
        <Checkout
            cart={cart}
            order={order}
            onCaptureCheckout={handleCaptureCheckout}
            error={errorMessage}
        />
    </Route>
</Switch>;
```

The `About` component

```
import React from 'react';

const About = () => {
    return <div>Tacos are delicious</div>;
};

export default About;
```

Comment: Can you provide with more code, the import et the url you are navigating to when going to about

Comment: Make sure you are using the same version of react-router-dom as the one used in the tutorial you are watching

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Route exact path="/about"> 
  <About />
</Route>
```

You seem to be passing an unnecessary prop by the same name as the component.

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work. It is still coming up blank. I am investigating if its because of the useLocation hooks in the file.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox/fiddle or provide me with a working example? @TremaineLedbetter